# Choose existing or creating new category

Tags: buttons, dropdown, modal-windows

Our current implementation gives the user an option to select a category from a drop-down and to add new category. The problem is that this button under the drop-down does not work very well.

1) Should we use radio buttons so the user can switch between "use existing" or "add new"

2) Use drop-down with button "add new" inside it.

It would be nice that the component would be mobile friendly as well since this is a responsive page.

Example of current solution:
[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does the user need to do in order to create a new category? Just set a name?

Comment: Yes, only one input field with name is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're prepared to put the work in to make it happen (it's not always an out-of-the-box control option), a *combo-box* is your friend here. The user can do any of the following:

- Type a whole new entry as if it was a text box
- Type a few characters and get an autocomplete dropdown for common/preset values
- Click the dropdown arrow & select from common/preset values without having to type

That way the whole lot can be done from a single control and in a single interaction, rather than having to click & type. They can also just start typing to see if the value they want already exists, rather than having to scroll through a dropdown that could easily get quite long to find out it's not there.